# Allow radio fields to be set to decheckable on second check

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I would like to be able to set a class name on the container around various radio groups on a page which would allow those radio groups to be uncheckable / detickable - thus allowing the user to set a radio field back to nothing. The names should be assumed to be dynamic so the code is as reusable as possible.  I think it is fair to assume that only one unique input name would occur within each element set with the class.

I am aware this is non-standard.

I am aware that similar questions have been put before.

The complexity of the question is handling multiple groups of radios with dynamically generated names in a simple and consistent way.  Generally most solutions I have seen keep track of the current selection either by applying classes to the radio inputs in some other way.  Any answers that care to discuss the pros and cons of the various events that are best listened to would also be of value.

Example html:

```
<ul class="detickable-radio">
  <li><input name="x1" type="radio" value="a" id="r_1_1"><label for="r_1_1">First Q First A</label></li>
  <li><input name="x1" type="radio" value="b" id="r_1_2"><label for="r_1_2">First Q 2nd A</label></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li><input name="y1" type="radio" value="c" id="r_2_1"><label for="r_2_1">Second Q First A</label></li>
  <li><input name="y1" type="radio" value="d" id="r_2_2"><label for="r_2_2">Second Q 2nd A</label></li>
</ul>
<ul class="detickable-radio">
  <li><input name="z1" type="radio" value="e" id="r_3_1"><label for="r_3_1">Third Q First A</label></li>
  <li><input name="z1" type="radio" value="f" id="r_3_2"><label for="r_3_2">Third Q 2nd A</label></li>
</ul>
```

Desired Result: the x1 and z1 radios would be uncheckable and the y1 radio would not be.

Vanilla and jQuery answers are both welcome. Cheers.

---

Update - I have set it as complete although it does not yet function for keyboard entry.  In general I would suggest that an approach of keeping track of the checked values and then checking on each change event would give better coverage.  Also I think that it would be neater to change checkboxes to allow a single value to be checked than to change a radio to detickable.  Also I can't believe Nevada isn't going to provide any further count updates for another day.

Comment: you can do it easily use the checkbox just change a CSS style to radio button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var s;
$('.detickable-radio input:radio, .detickable-radio input:radio ~ label').mousedown(function(e) {
  var $this = $(this).is(":radio") ? $(this) : $(this).prev();
  s = $this.is(":checked")
}).mouseup(function(e) {
  var $this = $(this).is(":radio") ? $(this) : $(this).prev();
  $this.prop("checked", !s)
}).click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
});
```

```js
var s;
$('.detickable-radio input:radio, .detickable-radio input:radio ~ label').mousedown(function(e) {
  var $this = $(this).is(":radio") ? $(this) : $(this).prev();
  s = $this.is(":checked")
}).mouseup(function(e) {
  var $this = $(this).is(":radio") ? $(this) : $(this).prev();
  $this.prop("checked", !s)
}).click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="detickable-radio">
  <li><input name="x1" type="radio" value="a" id="r_1_1"><label for="r_1_1">First Q First A</label></li>
  <li><input name="x1" type="radio" value="b" id="r_1_2"><label for="r_1_2">First Q 2nd A</label></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li><input name="y1" type="radio" value="c" id="r_2_1"><label for="r_2_1">Second Q First A</label></li>
  <li><input name="y1" type="radio" value="d" id="r_2_2"><label for="r_2_2">Second Q 2nd A</label></li>
</ul>
<ul class="detickable-radio">
  <li><input name="z1" type="radio" value="e" id="r_3_1"><label for="r_3_1">Third Q First A</label></li>
  <li><input name="z1" type="radio" value="f" id="r_3_2"><label for="r_3_2">Third Q 2nd A</label></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is good but it disables keyboard entry and doesn't work for common checking via the for attribute in the wrapping label. No tick!

Comment: @jamesgarrett Try now

Comment: I have deleted my answer, since @CarstenLøvboAndersen has already given a good answer +1 from me, and no need to edit mine.